# Do wifi cards on client devices adjust tx strength depending on signal?

Tags: signal, wifi

In trying to answer a question about wifi optimization in homes, one has to know whether a slightly lower signal on a client device (due to low TX setting on a router, for example) would normally be compensated by an increased TX strength (such as seems to be the case with GSM devices) on the client.

If that is normally the case, then perhaps it's safer to bet on higher TX power settings on the routers, than on the client devices for battery and health-related reasons.

If, on the other hand, the bulk of client devices don't vary the TX power, then the best thing to do is to bring the TX power on the routers to a minimal level at which good speed is attainable.

Update:
this edit is to dispute the closing as off topic.

The question was flagged as a "question a about use of electronics device" which is entirely untrue. The question is rather about the way transmission-reception components are programmed normally in wifi enabled devices.

According to [guide](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic),

> if your question generally covers ...
>
> - a specific electronics design problem
>
> and is not about ...
>
> - consumer electronics such as media players, cell phones or smart phones, except when designing these products or modifying their electronics for other uses

I should add that the question applies to any device using wi-fi signal, be it a plug and play router for home use or a park-wide system of antennae. It's about how to properly configure TX and RX in terms of power.

Comment: I think this is a common practice in duplex radio communication, to increase TX on client device when receive strength goes low. But it is not "compensation of settings", because the communication goes both ways: there is a channel model which assumes that if you can't receive well, the router will also hear you not well, so the client TX needs an increase.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that for most wifi cards a -65db signal would be "strong" signal, and thus the card would keep the TX levels low?

Comment: I assure you that the people who voted to close did not misunderstand your question; they have accurately categorized it.  In addition, your question is eligible for closure for being too broad, because the answer would be different for each and every model of wireless radio.

Comment: Ben, there's no need to assure me of anything. I am aware of how sites on this network work and of the amount of research you have to do before posting a question and of the minimum quality of the writing. All the rest is a matter of subjectivity.  Read [this](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2944/questions-on-things-electrical-get-closed-questions-on-adhesives-get-significan/2973#2973).

Answer (score 2):

Yes the Tx level starts at max power are  then reduced if the RSSI values are high enough to conserve energy and then reduced bit rates at max power if the error rate is too high.  The same is true for mobile phones near towers and fringe areas. But I won't get into the protocol for doing this and RSSI levels are normally not available to the user but are available with special utilites under Windows and other operating systems.

Comment: There are two RSSI values, one for each direction, and the question assumes, without any reason, that the wrong one is used in automatic power control.  It is important to note that compensating based on the wrong RSSI sets up a disastrous positive feedback loop which will break the connection.

Comment: Well, it's not entirely "without any reason". See, every time I come across a router in a small home/apartment I dial down the TX on the router to 40-50% and the signal is still -60db if not the same virtually in key areas of the home. Does this indicate a problem with "automatic configuration"? Hm, I believe it does. Hence the question.